# Git Status gives "Permission Denied" with some files

Tags: git, permissions

Here's a screenshot for the curious.

[image]

I don't know what could be the issue with these since I have the permissions to all project files permissions are chmod'd as 644.

Note : This is different than the "Git Permission Denied" results where most issues are related to SSH keys.

Comment: Thats the wrong directory listing. `ls ie`.

Comment: @tkausl Doh! Thanks! Your comment was enough to make me realize that the permissions weren't correct for that particular directory, hence my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue. Try this:

`sudo chmod 'g=rwx,u=rwx,o=x' <folder-containing-files>`

Answer (score 0):

`git status` is an intern function of your computer. 
It's a bit like a `diff` for git 
Try `ls -la` on the files 
May be restrictive usage is running on them